# WatchOS app ask for purchase again after successful previous purchase

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-watch, watchos

I developed an app for iOS and an independent app for watchOS. I have generated a promo code for this app (watch app). As proof, I present a screenshot for this:

[image]

It has been redeemed with success and after all on App Store on iOS it looks like:

[image]

So it all seem to be fine. But now it starts...

How can I install that app on my Watch? Two ways:

- using `Watch` app on iPhone:

[image]

but it is not displayed on the list of Available Apps. Why?

- using App Store on my Watch:

[image]

but it is not displayed as ready to download, instead it wants me to pay for it. Why?

Comment: Because you have not downloaded it to your phone?

Comment: Ok, but how to download it on my phone since it is an app for Watch? The app is completely independent from iOS App. It is not just Watch extension for main iOS App. It is completely different/separated/independent app in app store/xcode/appstoreconnect

Comment: I don't see what difference you think that makes. The iPhone is still the vector. I could download your app on my iPhone if I wanted to pay $10. Even a watch complication is downloaded and installed using the phone.

Comment: ok, so if you are right... how can I download it to an iPhone? There is no `Download` button in App Store. Is there any other way? Remember that the issue is related only to promo code... not when you want to pay for the app.

Comment: I don't have a promo code so I have no way of knowing that. Maybe this is an App Store bug. Hard to see how *programming* is involved.

Comment: I think this is an App Store bug... I already reported my issue and waiting for response. If you are interested in, I could give you one single promo code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer and solution is very simple. Try to purchase it again on the Watch and then you will see the following view:

[image]